# What is inotify_add_watch's fd parameter?

Tags: c, linux, inotify

I am working on a project to monitor folders and files, but I don't know how `inotify_add_watch` works. I searched online to see what `fd` does but I don't understand [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/inotify_add_watch.2.html):

> The `fd` argument is a file descriptor referring to the inotify instance whose watch list is to be modified.

What does that mean?

Comment: It's the descriptor returned by `inotify_init()` or `inotify_init1()`...

Comment: What is a descriptor

Comment: inotify_add_watch creates a file descriptor for what you are watching because the pathname can change or be deleted, but a file descriptor keeps a handle for as long as your program is running.

Answer (score 0):

fd is the return value of *inotify_init()* or *inotify_init1()*.

```
first,  use inotify_init() or inotify_init1() to initialize an inotify 
instance;
second, return a file descriptor (with a new inotify event queue) fd ;
third, use the returned fd in inotify_add_watch to monitor the file path 
you want to monitor.
```

example code :

```
  int fd = inotify_init();                
  int wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, argv[1], IN_ALL_EVENTS);                  
  
  for (;;) 

  {   
       fd_set fds;   
       FD_ZERO(&fds);                
       FD_SET(fd, &fds);   


       if (select(fd + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) > 0)       

       {   
           int len, index = 0;   
           while (((len = read(fd, &buf, sizeof(buf))) < 0) && (errno == EINTR));      
           while (index < len) 

           {   
                  event = (struct inotify_event *)(buf + index);                      
                  _inotify_event_handler(event);                                             
                  index += sizeof(struct inotify_event) + event->len;             
           }   
       }   
  }   
  
  inotify_rm_watch(fd, wd);             
  
  return 0;
```

Comment: @yanzhangguo I still didn't understand about it. I just asked a simple question that what is fd argument and why it is used in `inotify_add_watch`?

Answer (score 0):

A file descriptor is basically an identifier of some input/output resource. When you work with inotify, you need to initialize an instance with `inotify_init`, which returns a file descriptor, then you can add the files that you want to watch to the instance with `inotify_add_watch`.

So, answering your question, the fd argument in `inotify_add_watch` is the file descriptor of a inotify instance, returned by an `inotify_init` call.